# How to edit the data of an excel worksheet without affecting the other worksheets?

Tags: c#, excel

Suppose I have an excel file containing 4 sheets, Sheet 1, Sheet 2 and so on. I need to read data from a List object, truncate all the data of Sheet 1, and write the data from the List object into that Sheet 1, without affecting any other sheet..

This is what I have been trying..

```
string pathFileSource = "C:\\Temp\\Output.xls";
            string pathFileDestination = "C:\\Temp\\Performance Testing.xls";
            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook wbSource = excel.Workbooks.Open(pathFileSource, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            Excel.Workbook wbDestination = excel.Workbooks.Open(pathFileDestination, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            Excel.Worksheet WorksheetSource = wbSource.Sheets[1];
            //Copy all range in this worksheet
            WorksheetSource.UsedRange.Copy(Missing.Value);
            Excel.Worksheet WorksheetDestination = wbDestination.Sheets[1];
            // Select used Range, paste value only
            WorksheetDestination.UsedRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd, false, false);
            wbSource.Close();
            wbDestination.Save();
            wbDestination.Close();
            //Quit application
            excel.Quit();
```

Although I am getting alerts stating that the data has been added to Clipboard, the destination file is not getting updated with the correct data. Any pointers as to where I am going wrong?

I will be really grateful if someone can provide an actual working code, and not pseudocodes.

Answer (score 1):

This is (default)normal mode of MS Excel to edit one worksheet at a time and separately or independently of other worksheets. 
However, if you have created a Worksheet Group by selecting worksheet tabs, then first of all, you have to un-group the worksheets. Then you can handle every worksheet independently.
I hope this may help!
You can make a Group of worksheets by:
Press and hold CTRL key and click on worksheet tabs(left button click).

And un-group your worksheets by the same process again.